# Get-QADComputer -LdapFilter & NOT operator

Tags: active-directory, ldap, powershell

I'm having issues excluding an OU from my LDAP filter

```
$DaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)
$ft = $DaysAgo.ToFileTime()

Get-QADComputer -SizeLimit 0 -IncludeAllProperties
-SearchRoot 'DC=My,DC=Domain,DC=Local'
-LdapFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer)(lastLogonTimeStamp<=$ft)
(!(ou:dn:=DisabledPCs))(|(operatingsystem=Windows 2000 Professional)
(operatingSystem=Windows XP*)(operatingSystem=Windows 7*)
(operatingSystem=Windows Vista*)(operatingsystem=Windows 2000 Server)
(operatingsystem=Windows Server*)))"
```

I'm looking to query for all Windows OS systems that haven't logged in to AD for more than 31 days & that are not already in the OU "DisabledPCs", which is where I'll be moving them to.

When I run it now, I'm getting all the systems I'm looking for, including those in the "DisabledPCs" OU...  I've tried several variations including:

```
(&(!(ou:dn:=DisabledPCs)))
```

As well as putting it in different locations in the filter (not that I thought it would make a difference, but I obviously don't know that...)

Thanks in advance for any help,

-dboftlp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an FYI from a similar question over on stackoverflow

"AD doesn't support these kind of extensible match"
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295092/ldap-using-a-filter-to-avoid-a-sub-cn-in-active-directory)

What I've basically done is totally simplified the script with some help from powershellcommunity.org poster [*cameronove*](http://powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aff/4/aft/4970/afv/topic/Default.aspx) to come up with the following:

```
$DaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)
$ft = $DaysAgo.ToFileTime()
$StComps = Get-QADComputer -SizeLimit 0 -IncludeAllProperties `
-SearchRoot 'DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL' `
-LdapFilter "(&(&(lastLogonTimeStamp<=$ft)(operatingsystem=*Windows*)))" `
| Where { $_.dn -notmatch "DisabledPCs"}
```

I simplified the OS filter that helps me avoid other non Win OS's and piped the OU exclusion to not include the OU I want to move systems to later in my script.  I'm not including that part here, because I log it to an Excel workbook with a foreach loop and it's much more involved than my original Q?...

If you are interested in seeing the whole script, feel free to hit me up
@dboftlp on twitter
or via dboftlp at gmail dot com

Answer (score 1):

What I find easiest with LDAP filters is to break them up in the format below:  (Apache DS seems to do this automatically, which is really helpful).

```
(&
  (objectcategory=computer)
  (lastLogonTimeStamp<=$ft)
  (!
    (ou:dn:=DisabledPCs)
  )
  (|
   (operatingsystem=Windows 2000 Professional)
   (operatingSystem=Windows XP*)(operatingSystem=Windows 7*)
   (operatingSystem=Windows Vista*)
   (operatingsystem=Windows 2000 Server)
   (operatingsystem=Windows Server*)
  )
)
```

So I think maybe, if you reordered the filter more as:

```
(&
  (!
    (ou:dn:=DisabledPCs)
  )
  (
    (objectcategory=computer)
    (lastLogonTimeStamp<=$ft)
    (|
     (operatingsystem=Windows 2000 Professional)
     (operatingSystem=Windows XP*)(operatingSystem=Windows 7*)
     (operatingSystem=Windows Vista*)
     (operatingsystem=Windows 2000 Server)
     (operatingsystem=Windows Server*)
    )
  )
)
```

I did not test that, but I think making the & two part, the NOT, and then everything else by bracketing it off, ought to do it.

Let me know if that is any closer.